# Error after moving Laravel 10 User model to a different namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, eloquent-relationship

I recently moved the **`User`** model in my Laravel application from the **`App\Models\User`** namespace to **`App\Models\V1\User`**. I've updated all references, cleared caches, and executed **`composer dump-autoload`**. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Class \"App\\Models\\User\" not found",
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "...\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
    "line": 793,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "...\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
            "line": 315,
            "function": "newRelatedInstance",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "...\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
            "line": 284,
            "function": "morphInstanceTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "...\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\PersonalAccessToken.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "morphTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },

        ...
}
```

This is my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\V1;

use App\Models\V1\UserProfile;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * Get the related user profile.
     * 
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function profile(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserProfile::class, 'profile');
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the user has an admin profile.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAdmin(): bool
    {
        return $this->profile()->first()->title == 'admin';
    }

    /**
     * Route notifications for the mail channel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForMail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

I have move the rest of the models of the application to "V1" and they are working fine.
But when I try to do it with the User model, I keep getting this message and I'm out of ideas.

I've thoroughly checked my codebase, configuration files, and caches, but I still can't identify the source of this issue.

- Updated all references to App\Models\User to App\Models\V1\User.
- Cleared caches.
- Executed composer dump-autoload.
- Modify reference in auth config file.
- Deleted vendor folder and installed composer from scratch.
- Searched for references to "App\Models\User"

Can someone give me a hand with this, please?

Thanks!

Comment: my first look would have been at config/auth but as you said you have modified the references there as well, did you `php artisan optimize:clear` and then dump the autoload to clear the caches?

Comment: No, I've done **`php artisan config:clear`** **`php artisan cache:clear`**, **`php artisan config:cache`**, **`php artisan route:clear`**.
Nonetheless, I just did it, but I get the same error message.

Comment: It's in the database, in the table that stores the `PersonalAccessToken` model.

Comment: @Olivier Wow!!!  

Yes, it was exaclty that! 

I modified the value stored in the "tokenable_type" column within the "personal_access_token" table and it worked on the first run. I made a new login and the new token comes with the proper value "App\Models\V1\User".

Thank you so much!